# Nested update SQL Server and SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to have a query as below:

```
SELECT top (1) @AddressRepeatNum=a.CheckNumber FROM(
UPDATE dbo.SearchList SET CheckNumber=CheckNumber+1 
OUTPUT inserted.CheckNumber AS CheckNumber 
WHERE PageAddress=@Address and CheckNumber<6
) as a
```

but it doesn't work. How should I rewrite it to work?
In a simple word, I want to add one to a column of my table and then if it was larger than 5 then do something

Comment: What you get an error? Or just no data?

Comment: Actually, it is something, I have written to show what I need. It doesn't work absolutely.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Rewrite the query above to be compiled. I can write it using temporary tables but . it is to slow

Comment: Inside parenthesis currently works well. I need to know how check out check number after adding 1

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do a select directly on an update like that.  You insert the output information to a table variable and then you select from the table variable.

```
DECLARE @AddressRepeatNum INT, @Address varchar (500) = 'Test'
DECLARE @Check table (checknumber INT)
UPDATE dbo.SearchList SET CheckNumber=CheckNumber+1 
OUTPUT inserted.CheckNumber into @Check
WHERE PageAddress=@Address and CheckNumber<6

SELECT TOP (1) @AddressRepeatNum=CheckNumber 
FROM @check 
ORDER BY CheckNumber
```

Comment: I did it before but it was to slow. I am looking for a better solution